# How can I add a small snippet of code that uses request and runs when someone accesses the django admin page?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-request

How can I add a small snippet of code that runs when someone accesses the admin page. I am trying to get the IP address of users that use the admin  and make changes to the database. I can use `django signals` to see when changes are made, but I need to access django `request` in order to gain access to a user's IP address. I thought a simple way would be to just add a snippet of code in the the `admin views` where I would request the IP address and save it in a variable. I looked into overriding the django admin views, but everything I found seemed to be correlated with creating querysets and returning http request in some way, which is not what I want (I don't believe.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the save_model method in model admin class.

**admin.py**

```
class YouModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  ##
  def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.ip = request.get("get  ip address")
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Great. That works great in place of signals. Thanks.